# AngularJs scope undefined http.post data not usable

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm having a struggle with AngularJS

Template
ng-init="init(18)" // setting id = 18

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('sjbApp', []);

app.controller('sjbController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.eventId = {} // declaring scope model

  $scope.init = function(event_id) 
  {
        //alert(event_id);
        $scope.eventId = event_id; // setting scope.eventId model to 18
        console.log($scope.eventId);
  };

  getEventUsers(); // Load all available users for event 
  function getEventUsers(){ $http.post("http://localhost/sjb/public/admin/angular/events/deelnemers", { 'eventid': $scope.eventId } )
    .success(function(data){        
        $scope.eventusers = data; // getting data       
        console.log($scope.eventusers);     
    })
    .error(function() { 
        alert('fault!');                
    });
  };
```

PHP

```
print_r($request->all());
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[eventid] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

The console returns nothing and I'm not seeing what's wrong.
I'm a newbie with Angular so probably it's something simple.
Please help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Obviously (and not surprisingly) `getEventUsers` is executed before `init`. Call `getEventUsers();` from inside of `init`.

Comment: Something so simple and not seeing it by myself. Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: @dfsq Please post that comment as an answer. Then Jeba can accept it, and it will be of help to people searching for similar problems in future